# Implementing a DSL on ruby to generate nested folders and files structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dsl

I'am developing custom DSL to generate folders and files in a tree-like structure

### DSL (folders_tree.rb)

```
FoldersFilesGenerator::DSL.setup do
  root_folder_1 do

    root_folder_file_1

    subfolder_1 do

     subfolder_file_1
     subfolder_file_2

       sub_subfolder do
         ...
       end
    end

    subfolder_2 do
      ...
    end
    root_folder_file_2
  end

  root_folder_2 do
    ...
  end
end
```

### Generator

```
PATH = 'path/to/folders_tree.rb'

#FoldersFilesGenerator::Generator.new.generate
def generate
  instance_eval(File.read(PATH), File.basename(PATH), 0)
end
```

### DSL processor

```
module FoldersFilesGenerator
  class DSL

    attr_accessor :current_path

    def self.setup(*args, &block)
      new.instance_eval &block
    end

    def initialize
      @current_path = 'initial/root/folder'
    end

    def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
      if block_given?
        #need help here
        self.current_path = renew_path(@current_path)
        FileUtils.mkdir_p current_path #create nested folder
        instance_eval(&block)
      else
        FileCreator.create(m, @current_path) #create file on a current tree level
      end
    end


  private

  def renew_path(current_path)

  end

  end
end
```

I assume that my working path changes only when i dive deeper or emerge over my DSL blocks tree structure so i need to reassign my `current_path` there with a `renew_path` method, but i totally messed my code here. Please help.

The solution can be completely different. All I need that my DSL works like i described.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you want `renew_path` to do. It should be as easy as this:

```
if block_given?
  remembered_path = current_path
  self.current_path = File.join(current_path, m.to_s)
  FileUtils.mkdir_p current_path #create nested folder
  instance_eval(&block)
  self.current_path = remembered_path
else
```

Comment: "Keep it simple" =) Looks like just what i need! Thanks a lot!